# Using Binary Formatter with asynchronous sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, binaryformatter

I am trying to utilize the benefits of asynchronous sockets in C# with serializing/deserializing with BinaryFormatter, but am running into serveral issues. Mainly, I keep getting the error:

`No map for object 1953724755`

when trying to deserialize the network stream.

I've tried changing to a synchronous socket, and that seems to work fine, but when using an asynchronous one (with BeginRecieve and EndRecieve and such), I still get this error.

Here is the code where I am deserializing:

```cs
private void BeginDictionaryRecieve(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Stream socketStream = new NetworkStream(socketState.workSocket);
    IFormatter dataFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    socketState.workSocket.EndReceive(ar);
    List<string> rackthatWasClicked = (List<string>) 
        dataFormatter.Deserialize(socketStream);
    this.recievedListForRackDisplay = rackthatWasClicked;
    OnDataRecieved.Invoke();
    socketState.workSocket.BeginReceive(socketState.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,new AsyncCallback(BeginDictionaryRecieve), socketState);
}
```

And here is the serialization code (synchronous):

```cs
IPAddress ipAdd = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
TcpClient myClient = new TcpClient();
myClient.Connect(ipAdd, 8002);
Stream clientStream = myClient.GetStream();
IFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
f.Serialize(clientStream, ShelfDataToSend);
clientStream.Dispose();
myClient.Dispose();
```

I should note that I am using BinaryFormatter because I can't seem to find a way to serialize an object other than a string with normal .Write operations on a socket.

Comment: You got a notification that bytes were received in the socketState.buffer but Deserialize() is not using them.  So it keels over when it tries to deserialize from missing bytes.  Consider using a MemoryStream to store the received data, but you have to frame it so you know when you received them all.  Or use a Task so you don't need BeginReceive, a bit wasteful but certainly easier to get going.

Comment: @HansPassant if I use MemoryStream, would I gather all the recieved bytes into it, then try and deserialize the MemoryStream? Does BinaryFormatter allow that kind of operation? I can't seem to find anything in the documentation about it

Comment: BinaryFormatter.Deserialize can take any stream.  But you have to be sure that the MemoryStream contains the *exact* number of bytes required by BinaryFormatter, that's the problem.  Framing data with TCP is done by first transmitting the size of the byte[] so that the receiver knows how often to call Receive to get them all.   To know that size you have to likewise use MemoryStream at the transmit end.  Using Task to make it async will be a lot easier.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm sorry to ask, but do you think you could post an example as an answer? I'm having some trouble following

Comment: There are a lot of examples out there, google "c# tcp send byte array" to find them.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks man you were a great help. I posted the answer that ended up working for me, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Do annotate that this can only work if you close/dispose the socket after calling BinaryFormatter.Serialize().  It is not a common scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the direction from Hans, I was able to find a solution that works nicely. I'm now receiving data like this:

```cs
try
{
    StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket client = state.workSocket;

    int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        stream.Write(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(BeginDictionaryRecieve), state);
    }
    else
    {
        if (stream.Length > 1)
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            stream.Position = 0;
            this.recievedListForRackDisplay =(List<string>)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
            OnDataRecieved.Invoke();

            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                            new AsyncCallback(BeginDictionaryRecieve), state);
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception e)
{
    throw e;
}
```

It should also be noted that this solution only works if the client Socket is disposed of after sending its data.